# Какое событие Windows API будет полезным для реализации логгера сворачивай и разворачиваний окон?

Tags: winapi

1. Применение: (1) Например и юзера есть вредная привычка, "без понимания зачем так часто, если все новости решается уведомлениями" разворачивать и сворачивать некоторые окна, и нужно изменить его поведение логгированием, с целью он определил программы самые интересные. (2) Это прям классика слов Окна и API, WindowsAPI.
2. Техническая сторона: Нужно WinAPI событие которое будет содержать в себе "развернуть/свернуть", и патчнейм процесса, или PID.